# Extend desktop to second monitor on LXDE

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, monitor, lxde

I have connected external SVGA monitor to my asus 1025C that runs Ubuntu+LXDE. Currently both monitors show the same picture and second display has not native resolution.

I found only one place where I can adjust display setting -`Preferences>>Monitor settings` but there is nothing to setup regarding desktop extension on two monitors. Where I can find these settings?